# Using generic Type information in method

Tags: java, generics

I have a method who's definition looks like this:

```
public static <T> List fromInputStreamToObject(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception{
    List objects = null;
    try {
        if(inputStream!=null){
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));
            Type typeOfSrc = new TypeToken<JsonConverter<T>>(){}.getType();
            JsonConverter jsonConverter = getGson().fromJson(reader, typeOfSrc);
            if(jsonConverter!=null)
                objects = jsonConverter.getData();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return objects;
}
```

This doesn't give any compilation error, but

```
Type typeOfSrc = new TypeToken<JsonConverter<T>>(){}.getType();
```

gives the run time exception "Type 'T' is not a Class, ParameterizedType, or GenericArrayType. Can't extract class."

**How do i use the T to initialize my TypeToken instance?**

Comment: What is actually contained in your inputStream? Is it JSON representation of Class clazz? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve as JsonConverter interface doesn't have getData() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Type typeOfSrc = type(JsonConverter.class, clazz);

// type(C, A1,...,An) => C<A1,...,An>
static ParameterizedType type(final Class raw, final Type... args)
{
    return new ParameterizedType()
    {
        public Type getRawType(){ return raw; }

        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments(){ return args; }

        public Type getOwnerType(){ return null; }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used GSON in a few months, but as I recall: a Class is a Type. You would just pass your parameter "clazz" in place of the computed "typeOfSrc"

Comment: that didn't work.. it tried to convert the class defined by clazz to JsonConverter. 

Class definition of JsonConverted is Class JsonConverter<T>

Comment: and i'm not able to pass JsonConverter<some-class>.class as a parameter. Compiler doesn't recognize it.. i wonder why?